# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1 in circle ci

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, circleci

I updated the gradle plugin to the latest version : `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1`  and this error occured in AS:

```
export TERM="dumb"
if [ -e ./gradlew ]; then ./gradlew test;else gradle test;fi

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring root project 'Android-app'. Could not
 resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'. Could not
 find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1. Searched in the
 following locations:
 https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha1/gradle-3.0.0-alpha1.pom
 https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha1/gradle-3.0.0-alpha1.jar
 Required by:
```

Current CI config circle.yml

```
dependencies:
   pre:
      - mkdir -p $ANDROID_HOME"/licenses"
      - echo $ANDROID_SDK_LICENSE > $ANDROID_HOME"/licenses/android-sdk-license"
      - source environmentSetup.sh && get_android_sdk_25

   cache_directories:
    - /usr/local/android-sdk-linux
    - ~/.android
    - ~/.gradle
   override:
    - ./gradlew dependencies || true

test:
  post:
    - mkdir -p $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/junit/
    - find . -type f -regex ".*/target/surefire-reports/.*xml" -exec cp {} $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/junit/ \;

machine:
    java:
        version: oraclejdk8
```

Edit:
My gradle file :

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
      url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.1.3"
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 359, accepted):

Google have new maven repo

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/10/android-studio-30.html > section **Google's Maven Repository**

https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven

So add the dependency on maven repo:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        // You need to add the following repository to download the
        // new plugin.
        google() // new which replace https://maven.google.com
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'  //Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.6.
    }
}
```

Comment: if you run intro constraint error use add thse :  mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

Comment: You shouldn't need to add `mavenCentral()`. Because `jcenter()` shoudl be enough: https://www.jfrog.com/knowledge-base/why-should-i-use-jcenter-over-maven-central/
https://blog.bintray.com/2015/02/09/android-studio-migration-from-maven-central-to-jcenter/

Comment: I add 
maven {
          url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
this to gradle script,and build it.
I get this error:
Gradle sync failed: No route to host
How can I resolve this problem

Comment: try to open website: https://maven.google.com in browser, you will see, that it looks like they have error/downtime :/

Comment: @sud007 - How'd you know the latest is 3.0.0-alpha3? I can't find references for anything past alpha1, and the maven search sites only show 2.x

Comment: @Parker I am using **Android Studio 3.0 - Canary Channel**. Here is the **top level `build.gradle` classpath** `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4`, copied as is. Please notice that it is now **alpha4** after a update last week

Comment: @sud007 oh man, I didn't make the connection that the Gradle and Android studio are the same version. Thanks!

Comment: `url 'maven.google.com';` is now replaced with `google()` so please update: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#apply_plugin

Comment: I removed 'maven.google.com' from buildscript and allprojects, and only add google() on allprojects, and my problem gets fixed. thank you!

Comment: This should be edited in the build.gradle of the **Project** (not app level)

Comment: I have to use `url "https://maven.google.com"` to migrate to 3.0.0, then I can use `google()`.

Comment: We will never have a PERMANENT STANDARDS for this; Gosh, every day a changing !! :-/ and remember that Rep. **google()** is for Gradle 4.1 and up

Answer (score 108):

For things to compile via command line I needed to include the maven repo in BOTH `buildscript` and `allprojects`.

root `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2'
        ...
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

It's needed in the `buildscript` block to find the AGP, and in `allprojects` block to find `android.arch` and `com.android.databinding` packages (and others)

UPDATE:
It looks like the new repo is just called `google()` but I still needed to declare it in both places.

Comment: Pay attention to the update: *needed to declare it in both places* was the solution for me, repositories and allprojects

Comment: maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

when i place it , it work for me

Comment: just replace google() with this -> maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } then connect your VPN and sync again. Google makes life tough for Iranians, I wish you the worst google! I really miss Eclipse.

Answer (score 34):

To synchronize all of the answers here and elsewhere:

> ```
> buildscript {
>   repositories {
>     google() 
>     jcenter()
>   }
>   dependencies {
>     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
>
>   } }
> ```

Make your buildscript in build.gradle look like this. It finds all of them between google and jcenter. Only one of them will not find all of the dependencies as of this answer.

Comment: I had to add this to the `allprojects` as well and run `android/gradlew --stop` before trying again. Then it worked.

Comment: I had `repositories { jcenter() google() }` and it was not working... Reversing the order to  `repositories { google() jcenter() }` fixed the problem

Comment: JCenter Maven repository is no longer receiving updates: Replace with mavenCentral()

Answer (score 24):

For **Iranian** people: We need use **proxy** or **VPN** to building app.

Reason: The boycott by Google's servers causes that you can't build app or upgrade your requirement.

Comment: Can we use offline repository for specific version ?

Comment: @MrSalesi ofc not :(

Answer (score 16):

mtrakal's solution worked fine.

Added to gradle.build:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; 
        // they belong in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Then it automatically upgraded to alpha2.

Invalidate the caches and restarted all is fine.

File | Invalidate Caches / Restart

choose 'Invalidate & Restart'

Comment: JCenter Maven repository is no longer receiving updates: Replace with mavenCentral()

Answer (score 8):

I did this:

click SDk Manager:

[image]

Change in updates to Canary Channel, check and update it...

[image]

After go in build.gradle and change the compile version to 26.0.0-beta2:

[image]

After go in gradle/build.gradle and change dependencies classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha7':

[image]

After sync the project...
It works to me!
I hope I've helped... tks!

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you add following line in your top level build.gradle and that should fix it.

```
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
```

I got exact same error you mentioned above, once I added this entry everything worked.

Comment: tried and got this :    > Could not find com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2.

Comment: I think it would help if you post your app/build.gradle and build.gradle. Also try to use File -> Invalidate Cache optionm restart android studio see if things get better.

Answer (score 3):

For me I solved this error just by adding this line inside repository

```
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Incredibly frustrating, but the Google redirect of the `maven.google.com` repo seems to mess with loading the resources. If you instead set your repository to

`maven { url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2' }`

the files will resolve. You can prove this out by attempting to get the fully qualified resource at `https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha1/gradle-3.0.0-alpha1.pom` [3.0.0 Alpha](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha1/gradle-3.0.0-alpha1.pom)

This is because currently the `gradle:3.0.0-alpha1` is only being served via the new `'https://maven.google.com'` repository, but the site currently 404s at that location otherwise, being a public directory, you'd see a tree listing of all the files available by simply navigating to that location in your browser. When they resolve their outage, your CI build should pass immediately.

Comment: The repository [https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2] isn't available anymore...

Answer (score 1):

I find this at google: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

It mentiones that we need to

1. Update Gradle version to gradle-4.1-all ( change`gradle-wrapper.properties` by `distributionUrl=\https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`
2. Add  google() to repositories `repositories {   google() }` and `dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta7'  }`

You may require to have Android Studio 3

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but this doesn't fix the problem because this problem occurs AFTER you actually migrate to new gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio (Preview) sometimes recommends updating to a Gradle Plugin that is not available yet (did Google forget to publish it?). Such as today with

> 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-beta1'

I found I can see current versions of com.android.tools.build:gradle here, and then I just pick the newest:

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html

I just found this beta1 gradle bug in the [Android Bug Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72322569). I also just learned Android Studio > Help Menu > Submit Feedback brought me to the bug tracker.

Found temporary solution at [androiddev reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/7s916b/android_studio_31_canary_9_is_now_available/dt33e5r/) for the 3.1.0-beta1 problem: Either roll back to Preview Canary 8, or switch to gradle plugin 3.0.1 until Canary 10 is released shortly.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I forgot that I added a proxy in `gradle.properties` in `C:\Users\(current user)\.gradle` like:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=****
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8850
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem when update android studio from 3.2 to 3.3 and test every answers that i none of them was working. at the end i enabled Maven repository and its work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        google() 
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0' 
    }
}
```

It works...Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

My free advice is simply add **mavenCentral()** and **google()** in /build.gradle, or one of them how google advises on the official page. Should be something like this:

```
allprojects {
...
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        ...
        google()
    }
...
}
```