# Can I programmatically enable/disable settings option in android tablet keyboard?

Tags: android, android-keypad

I want to disable the keyboard settings button programmatically in Android tablet, I would like to disable the free-writing and other settings options in my project. please help me to solve the problem. Below I have attached the image.It will explain my query.[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is your concern behind that? Why would you care how does the user provide the input to your `EditText`?

Comment: The concern  I have here is. I want to keep the design static for all the users who use the particular kiosk at different times. But having this edit will allow them to change the keyboard as per their wish, which might affect the other user. One more thing is client requires us to block this feature, which makes sense considering it affects the static feature needed from the keyboard.

Comment: If its for a kiosk, why not kiosk mode and use a keyboard without the unwanted features: https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html

Comment: firstly, keyboard is just a regullar application. So the keyboard may not have this button at all, if it's developer does not implement it. Or hvae it in another place, or have options opened for example by gesture, or anything else. So you basically want to disable something, you even don't know if it exists, or how to find it in another app. That's why it is impossible with your approach.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I tried to implement the project which u mentioned, following error will occur "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071080/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle3-0-0-alpha1-in-circle-ci". I really worried about am I going to fix this issue or else some other things to do.