# could not find gradle 3.0.0-alpha4

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

a few days ago i have installed android studio 3.0 (preview) and after that in stable version (studio 2.3.3) when i try to import project it give me an error.
In preview everything works fine.
this is an error:

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha4/gradle-3.0.0-alpha4.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha4/gradle-3.0.0-alpha4.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha4/gradle-3.0.0-alpha4.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha4/gradle-3.0.0-alpha4.jar
Required by:
    project :
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1 in circle ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071080/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle3-0-0-alpha1-in-circle-ci)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> If you're opening an existing project using Android Studio 3.0 Preview
>   1 or later, follow the prompts to automatically update your project to
>   the latest version of the Android plugin. To manually update your
>   project, include the maven repo and change the plugin version in your
>   project-level build.gradle file as follows:

Open your <kbd>Project level</kbd> **`build.gradle`** Section .

You should add **`maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }`** .

**Example**

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
             // You need to add the following repository to download the new plugin.
             maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4' // Same for alpha6

        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have added buildsctipt and allprojects but it doesn't work

Comment: Could you share your `build.gradle`

Comment: `Clean-Rebuild` and `Restart` your IDE

Comment: @TornikeQurdadze wrong . You have two `build.gradle` .One is project level and another module level

Comment: how to add this maven repo on init script?

Answer (score 2):

A better way may be just to use

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}
```