# The android gradle plugin version 3.0.0-alpha1 is too old

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

While building a default project (black template) on Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1, I got the below error.

```
The android gradle plugin version 3.0.0-alpha1 is too old, please update to the latest version. To override this check from the command line please set the 
ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to "d27b293f4c7c48dfe922ba160164f3fa511cb3b9" 
Upgrade plugin to version 3.0.0-alpha1 and sync project Open File
```

What's wrong with the default setting?

Answer (score 7):

Your code may be containing an outdated gradle plugin version (may be `alpha1`, or something like that) in your project build.gradle file. Update it to the latest `alpha4` plugin like below:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the alpha1 is obsolete, even though it is not mentioned anywhere in document I could find.

In the project build.gradle, just change from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'
```

Comment: Yes . I hope you maintain this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44645099/could-not-find-gradle-3-0-0-alpha4/44645129#44645129

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya - I am getting problem in my project... it isnt compiling with apha4 .. showing problems in manifest... it worked fine before this

Comment: @Udit Kapahi, Try alpha5

Comment: @Elye I got it working by adding  android.enableAapt2=false to the gradle.properties file.

Comment: Using `android.enableAppt2=false` is not ideal, it is basically turning off the latest feature. It shouldn't be a long term solution.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps :

- Go to your Project structure
- Click on project on left side panel
- Update the Gradle version to 3.3
- Click on Ok Button

let it sync and you will be done

Comment: I would like to work on the latest Gradle version 4.0.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html I guess 3.3 is the latest supported version check out this link

Comment: @MRX Gradle 4.0 available. Refer https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

gradle:3.0.0-alpha1 was supported till date. Maybe alpha4 will do the trick.

Comment: Cool I was not aware about it ... Thanks I will go through it

Answer (score 1):

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'

its not recommended to use +

Answer (score 0):

After trying this solutions, I came with this:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'
  }
}
```

add

```
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
```

to buldscript repositories.