# Could not find com.android.tools.build.gradle:3.0.0-alpha7

Tags: android, build.gradle

I update the gradle plugin to the latest, and i'm getting this error:

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build.gradle:3.0.0-alpha7:.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Users/dmin/Documents/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha7//3.0.0-alpha7-.pom
    file:/C:/Users/dmin/Documents/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha7//3.0.0-alpha7-.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha7//3.0.0-alpha7-.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha7//3.0.0-alpha7-.jar
    https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha7//3.0.0-alpha7-.pom
    https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha7//3.0.0-alpha7-.jar
```

Here's my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build.gradle:3.0.0-alpha7'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Where i'm getting wrong? since i modified my gradle.build according to the question [Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1 in circle ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071080/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle3-0-0-alpha1-in-circle-ci)
 thank you!!

-- Updated the build.gradle according to Mr Tim, but i'm still having the same error

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build.gradle:3.0.0-alpha7'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1 in circle ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071080/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle3-0-0-alpha1-in-circle-ci)

Comment: At least do some research before posting such question ! It's answer is already there .

Comment: yes i have android studio 3 canary 7 installed

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Follow the steps in the [3.0.0 plugin migration guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html)

> **Update gradle version**
>
> The new Android plugin requires Gradle version 4.1-milestone-1 or
>   higher. If you're opening an existing project using Android Studio 3.0
>   Preview 5 or later, follow the prompts to automatically update an
>   existing project to the compatible version of Gradle.
>
> To update Gradle manually, update the URL in gradle-wrapper.properties
>   as follows:
>
> ```
> distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-milestone-1-all.zip
> ```

and

> **Apply the plugin**
>
> If you're opening an existing project using Android
>   Studio 3.0 Preview 5 or later, follow the prompts to automatically
>   update your project to the latest version of the Android plugin. To
>   manually update your project, include the maven repo and change the
>   plugin version in your project-level build.gradle file as follows:
>
> ```
> buildscript {
>   repositories {
>     ...
>     // You need to add the following repository to download the
>     // new plugin.
>     jcenter()
>     google()
>   }
>
>   dependencies {
>
>     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'  //Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.6
>   } 
> }
> ```

Comment: Wow, I believe that solved my issue. Why isn't `google()` included in repositories automatically when you update to Android Studio 3.0.0+ if it's necessary? x]

Answer (score 25):

You try :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        // You need to add the following repository to download the
        // new plugin.
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
```

Credits: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

Answer (score 13):

If you're in Android Studio 3.1 or higher, you're likely encounter such type of issue prompting by a `Build` window.
[image]

Simply click on the `Add Google Maven repository and sync project` option at right side and initiate another gradle sync.

It'll make the necessary changes in both `gradle-wrapper.properties` as well as `build.gradle` files.

Answer (score 4):

Update gradle plugin : in gradle.properties file 
add this line 
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`

then apply ther plugin in build.gradle file :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    ...
    // You need to add the following repository to download the
    // new plugin.
    google()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
}
```

}

Comment: I reinstalled java 8 sdk, restarted project and second option from last was "add google repo" that worked for me.. android 3.1 is trash

Answer (score 3):

the distributionUrl property inside gradle-wrapper.properties should be:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`

that works for me

Answer (score 0):

1. open the file path(just as the log said):
   `file:/C:/Users/dmin/Documents/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/`
2. [found this file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oznah.jpg)
3. just change `classpath 'com.android.tools.build.gradle:3.0.0-alpha7'`
   to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build.gradle:* * * '`   ;   `* * *` is the exist gradle file;

   this problem is because of gradle file do not found

Comment: Each of the folders that you show in stage 2 contains many files. How do I know the right file? I am also using an updated version of android studio so my folders are named differently. Is it possible for you to update your answer.