# Could not find com.android.tools.build:graddle - Links return 404

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I'm trying to run `react-native run-android` on a (kinda old) project of a friend. I'm getting this error:

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar
     Required by:
         project :
```

I tried to enter the links, and they are returning a 404 error. Are this links placed in a configuration file? Where do I get valid links for those files? Which file to modify to get said files?

Comment: Try to find in outher repository

Comment: Please refer: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45188703/could-not-find-com-android-tools-build-gradle3-0-0-alpha7/45188917 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515676/gradle-4-1-issue-on-latest-android-studio-3-0-1

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by adding the `google()` to the repositories, on the `android/app/build.gradle` file. Final result looks like

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```