# Android Studio "Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1"

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to build an Andoid Studio project and failing.  I cloned the repo. from GitHub, including:  build.gradle, gradle-wrapper.properties, gradle.properties, settings.gradle and local.properties.

When I try to build, the Build window shows:

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar
Required by:
    project :photo-crop-library
Open File
```

Note there is no 'just fix it' link in the above message.  The text "Open File" is a link which, when clicked, opens build.gradle, which contains

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

That first *classpath* line **used** to contain *classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'* but I followed the advice in [Could not find com.android.tools.build.gradle:3.0.0-alpha7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45188703/could-not-find-com-android-tools-build-gradle3-0-0-alpha7/45188917) to change to 3.2.1, but it didn't fix it.

Looking at the links in the error message, going to https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle, the highest version link shown on that page is 2.5.0-alpha-preview-02 so it looks like the link is wrong.  I am a complete Android Studio newbie;  how do I change that link?  *About Android Studio* shows:

```
Android Studio 3.3
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5199772, built on December 25, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.18.5-gentoo.efi
```

Thanks in expectation of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that error message does not match the provided `build.gradle` the least ...

because it originates from module `:photo-crop-library`, which has it's own `build.gradle`.

a) try updating to:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

b) try to place repository `google()` in the line above `jcenter()`.