# Could not find com.andorid.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am not able to solve the issue of associated with the gradle file.For Solving this issue i have downloaded the android studio 3.0 beta 6, in which the project is not builded. And in Android studio 2.3.2 following issue came

**top level gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta6'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.2.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**issues**

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-beta2/gradle-3.0.0-beta2.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-beta2/gradle-3.0.0-beta2.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-beta2/gradle-3.0.0-beta2.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-beta2/gradle-3.0.0-beta2.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-beta2/gradle-3.0.0-beta2.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-beta2/gradle-3.0.0-beta2.jar
Required by:
    project :
```

**EDIT:**
Just added the google maven repo:

**top level gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
    dependencies {
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta6'

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta6'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.2.2'
    }
}

//allprojects {
//    repositories {
//        jcenter()
//        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
//        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
//    }
//}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Gradle wrapper**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
#distributionUrl= https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-rc-1-all.zip
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
Just after uncommenting the `allproject` block

**error**
[image]
How can this issue be solved? I have watched many solution on stack but not able to solve this issue

Comment: have you try to remove beta2 from classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

Comment: no. i have not tried that

Comment: Ok than you must try it classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

Comment: Do i have to Remove the previous one and add new one

Comment: u can nonly put this:----------  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

Comment: Same issue on changing 

//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154886/discussion-between-ghimire-and-nd1010).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1 in circle ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071080/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle3-0-0-alpha1-in-circle-ci)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have SOlved this issue by using the Android Studio 3.0 Beta2. I have just changed the gradle dependencies as follows

**top level gradle dependencies**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.2.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> I have just changed beta6 to beta2.I dont know how it works fine but it is working fine

Answer (score 13):

You have to add the **maven google** also in the `buildscript` block in the **top-level** `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
       ...
       // You need to add the following repository to download the
       // new plugin.
       maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta6'
       //...
   }
}
```

This version of the plugin also requires an update version of gradle. You have to update the `distributionUrl` in `gradle-wrapper.properties` as follows:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

More info about the [plugin 3.0.x here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html).

Comment: where do i have to add these??

Comment: In to your ProjectLevel gradle file

Comment: @Ghimire In your top-level file. You have just to add another repo. Also you can use the latest beta-6.

Comment: @ND1010_ You don't need to add this part in the project build.gradle. Since the buildscript block is in the top-level file, just use it.

Comment: @Ghimire In the answer there is the link with all details about the migration. You have to upldate also the gradle version

Comment: i am waiting for gradle sync. :)

Comment: @gabrieleMariotti Doesn't this work
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip  ???quiery

Comment: @Ghimire what do you mean?

Comment: @gabrieleMariotti when i finish gradle sync it suggest me to use android studio 3.0 .When i open in android studio 3.0 the project is not builded.Updated with my gradle file

Comment: @Ghimire uncomment the `allprojects` block. it is required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154948/discussion-between-ghimire-and-gabriele-mariotti).

Answer (score 3):

```
repositories {
   jcenter()
   ...
   // You need to add the following repository to download the
   // new plugin.
   maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } //THIS
   google() //OR THIS
}
```

Also delete .gradle and gradle folder and resync the project. Issues with caches