# Android Studio - Flutter Project - "Build Failed with an exception"

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

**Please help me guys :( 
I'm trying to run the the flutter app in android studio on an android "Nexus 6" simulator 
but when i click the run button i get this message:**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not download builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.5.0)
  >   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.5.0/builder-3.5.0.jar'.
  >   Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 8174407; received: 4456416
  >   Could not download bundletool.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.9.0)
  >   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.9.0/bundletool-0.9.0.jar'.
  >   Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 5248142; received: 4456416
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19m 23s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it by deleting  http and https proxy in global gradle.properties file

Comment: check this link too,it might be useful,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071080/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle3-0-0-alpha1-in-circle-ci