# Android Studio: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2 during import an Eclipse project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to build this project https://github.com/vocollapse/Blockinger with Android Studio by importing it, because I suppose it was an Eclipse project earlier.
After import, it gives me the following message:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2.
```

I was finding solutions for this trouble, but found nothing that might help. Could someone suggest me how to fix this error and open/build this project correctly? I'm new in Android development and may not understand some specific details

Comment: The Git repository you have linked is over 7 years old. Since then, Google has changed Maven respiratory. Try looking adding the Google respiratory to your Gradle file, and see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44071571/12989672

Comment: Ok, I have added google() to buildscript -> repositories, but now it writes "Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.6.4". What should I do now? (I was trying earlier to install 5.6.4 from Terminal, but it led to other errors)

Comment: In Android Studio, see File→Settings→Build, Execution, Deployment→Build Tools→Gradle→ and check "Use default Gradle wrapper" and try again. If it is still an issue, check for any available updates to Android Studio.

If all else fails check "Use local gradle distribution" and point to the local binaries, using a complete .zip release of Gradle from their website.

Comment: Thanks, setting "distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-bin.zip" in gradle-wrapper.properties has solved the problem for this once

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved with the following steps:
1. Add `google()` to `buildscript -> repositories`
2. Set `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-bin.zip` in `gradle-wrapper.properties`