# Trying to import an eclipse ADT project into android studio but gradle fails

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

[image: gives the error as 'could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0]

It is an eclipse adt based android application,facing the mentioned error while importing the project into android studio,please help.

error: 'could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1 in circle ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071080/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle3-0-0-alpha1-in-circle-ci)

Comment: @EmmanuelChebbi this is resulting in error:Minimum supported gradle version is 6.1.1

Comment: Well I guess your version of Android Studio requires at least Gradle 6.1.1 then. I'm not used to Gradle but have you tried replacing 4.0.0 by 6.1.1? I've also seen several topics that discuss this error on StackOverflow and which may help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure 'Android SDK tools' is updated and whether you have installed the latest version of eclipse - 2020.06. Also sync project from gradle files. If you have done these already, tell me.

Comment: Android Studio is based on IntelliJ, I don't think that installing latest Eclipse IDE release is relevant here.

Comment: I've updated 'android sdk tools' and synced the project from gradle files but still the error persist.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0` is available in jcenter. But it surely [exists](https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.0/gradle-4.0.0.jar) in maven.google.com. Please try adding `google()` repository:

```
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
```

Also you need to make sure that AndroidStudio version matches `com.android.tools.build:gradle` version. I.e. version `4.0.0` works best with Android Studio 4.0