# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

solved [Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 ( or any version )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63157065/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle4-0-1-or-any-version)

Error :

Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1.
Searched in the following locations:

- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom
  Required by:
  project :
  Open File

---

build.gradle(Project):

```
 buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {

    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"

   
}


}



 allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://jitpack.io'
    }
    google()
}

}



task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Mon Jul 27 15:16:19 IRDT 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

---

looks like google() and jcenter() are not working as expected.

I just migrated from android studio 2.3.3 to 4.0.1 .

what is my problem????
tell me if you need more information .

thank you for your answer :)

Comment: You'll have to change your IP or, using proxies. Also make sure offline gradle toggle is not enabled.

Comment: I did these solutions. but not change

Comment: Try this: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip` in your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file.

Comment: I tried. don't change

Comment: Always works => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071080/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle3-0-0-alpha1-in-circle-ci

Comment: SOLVED https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63157065/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle4-0-1-or-any-version

Answer (score 5):

Try to put the google() as the first one in the repositories list in the gradle file to solve this issue.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```