# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 ( or any version )

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, jcenter

Error :

Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1. Searched in the following locations:

https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom

Required by: project : Open File

*** looks like google() and jcenter() are not working as expected.***

I migrated from android studio 2.3.3 to 4.0.1 and this error happened.

what is my problem???? plz tell me if you need more information .

thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Have you tried clearing your build directory and rebuilding the project from scratch?

Comment: yeah. that's not work

Comment: Please use `mavenCentral()` for dependencies repository entry, `jcenter()` will be deprecated https://developer.android.com/studio/build/jcenter-migration

Comment: Entering the 6 lines in my gradle.properties from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63235324/4833705 by @Sadegh is what fixed it for me. I described it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74113127/4833705

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**This solution may only work in Iran. If you know that's working out of Iran, please let others know.**

**Why would a proxy be necessary? There have been a number of technology-related sanctions against Iran.**

## Windows

go to -> File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | HTTP Proxy,
and choose -> manual proxy configuration. set **host name: fodev.org**
and set **port number: 8118**. now you must find **gradle.properties** file. that must be in:
Windows: C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME.gradle\gradle.properties OR for
Linux: ~/.gradle/gradle.properties .
if it does't exist, create that yourself and copy this:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=fodev.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8118
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.jitpack.io, *.maven.org
systemProp.https.proxyHost=fodev.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8118
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.jitpack.io, *.maven.org
```

## Mac

Open Network settings by  > System Preferences > Network. Then, choose your wifi and click on advanced, which is located on bottom-right of the panel (if there’s a lock  at the bottom left of the Network pane, click it to unlock the preference pane). A window would open in which you should go under "Proxies" tab and then check the box for "Web Proxy (HTTP)". There is a textfield named "Web Proxy Server" in which you should set it to `fodev.org` and in the next textfield you can enter the port number which is `8118` in this case. The steps may vary depending on the version of macOS and more information about procy server settings can be found on [Apple Support Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/enter-proxy-server-settings-on-mac-mchlp25912/12.0/mac/12.0). You can also take a look at the screenshot.

[image: macOS proxy settings]

The last step is to make sure that have `gradle.properties`. On finder, choose Go > Go to Folder and then paste `~/.gradle/` and go (alternatively, you can trigger this menu by holding shift + command + G). If you don't see anyfile under the name of`gradle.properties`, create it with textedit or terminal and paste this code there:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=fodev.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8118
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.jitpack.io, *.maven.org
systemProp.https.proxyHost=fodev.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8118
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.jitpack.io, *.maven.org
```

Now, you can run your project.

**IMPORTANT** : After installation of build.gradle 4.0.1 (or any version), restore this settings to previous state and remove the codes.

Comment: thank you man, it took me a week to solve this. cant we use psiphon instead?

Comment: @Ali.Rashidi you are welcome. I don't think so. vpn not working and we must use proxy.

Comment: It used to work with proxy or VPN, but it can't sync anymore. I suggest this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50291289/download-and-install-android-studio-gradle-offline

Comment: @Ehsan It's ok for me and there is no problem with sync. i 've been using it for months

Comment: The best solution ever, I live in Syria and suffer from gradle sync ban, nothing worked with me but your solution, you deserve 10 upvotes

Comment: Some companies may use WAF solutions and this may cause a problem retrieving certain URLs from the repositories. You may need to use a proxy/VPN or add the WAF certificate into your Android Studio's cacert file (the only caveat: you need to set the modified cacert file's timestamp the same as the original, otherwise Android Studio will complain; another issue you need to do this for every Android Studio update).

Comment: thanks Sadegh. my problem was resolved with your help :) Thank you

Comment: I was stuck with an issue for 2 days. I updated my `Firebase BoM` and the dependencies were no longer recognized. Upon further research the issue was: `PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`. Once I added the 6 lines in my `gradle.properties` file, everything worked. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 3):

Deleting and reinstalling my node modules seemed to work for me

```
rm -rf node_modules
yarn install
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are importing a project from github or other.

1. Close the project in Android Studio. File -> Close project.
2. In file explorer, delete .idea, .gradle and gradle if there are any inside your project folder. (.idea, .gradle are hidden items. Make sure hidden items are shown in your file explorer) or if you are using command line, do `ls -a`
3. Open the project in Android Studio again.
4. Done.