# Android Studio Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1. Error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom
Required by:
    project :
Open File
```

that is the error log.
I searched in many websites and all I got was to add `google()` in `build.gradle` file witch android studio has already done it.

I tried `mavenCentral()` too but that error still exist.
I installed AS 3.1 then I upgraded it to 4.0.1 which is the latest stable version.

the build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Edited:**
I can download `https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom` manually but anyone knows where to copy and paste it?

Comment: make sure you have enabled offline working or you are not connected to active internet so AS can download and save the lib in the cache directory of AS

Comment: @faiiziiawan I tried offline mode and I got the error `No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 available for offline mode.` So... Anything else?

Comment: then you need to build project with active internet

Comment: @faiiziiawan I tried that too. Didn't work.

Comment: what is your android studio version ? it should be v4 
check in help->about section

Comment: @faiiziiawan that's 4.0.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219135/discussion-between-mohammad-mostafa-dastjerdi-and-faiizii-awan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem for days and i solved that yesterday.
check my answer here :
[Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 OR 4.0.0 OR any versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63157065/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle4-0-1-or-4-0-0-or-any-versions/63235324#63235324)