# Execution failed for task:app:checkDebugAarMetadata

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-studio

When I'm building my project getting this kind of error:

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > E:\Ogma\instabeauty-client-v2\node_modules\react-native-firebase\android\build\intermediates\aar_metadata\debug\aar-metadata.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > E:\Ogma\instabeauty-client-v2\node_modules\react-native-device-info\android\build\intermediates\aar_metadata\debug\aar-metadata.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > E:\Ogma\instabeauty-client-v2\node_modules@react-native-community\viewpager\android\build\intermediates\aar_metadata\debug\aar-metadata.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)

I'm Using Android Studio 4.1
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6858069, built on September 23, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1237M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true

I've searched a lot but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: I have the same problem. that should be a new issue in android studio 4.1

Comment: I solved this issue right now! I just tried with change proxy in this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63157065/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle4-0-1-or-4-0-0/63235324#63235324  that worked for me. try with that.