# Could not get https:////dl.bintray.com/lukaville/maven/com/nbsp/library/1.09

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, bintray, jcenter

I am getting an error as shown below.

Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/lukaville/maven/com/nbsp/library/1.09/library-1.09.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

The Gradle configurations are shown below. Any help is appreciated.

I tried syncing the project, invalidate cache and restart, but nothing is working.

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.qdocs.smartschool"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "3.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'RestrictedApi'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://d1.bintray.com/lukaville/maven"
    }
    jcenter() } dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.2.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mindorks:paracamera:0.2.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1"
    implementation 'com.nbsp:library:1.09'

} apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**build.gradle(android_app_src)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url  "https://dl.bintray.com/lukaville/maven"
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I get that too trying your url in a pc browser

Comment: maybe require a proxy. check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63157065/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle4-0-1-or-any-version/63235324#63235324

Answer (score 3):

JFrog have shut down [Bintray](https://bintray.com/). You need to move to an alternative.

See some articles providing examples of changes needed.

- https://www.infoq.com/news/2021/02/jfrog-jcenter-bintray-closure/
- https://testfairy.com/blog/jcenter-and-bintray-is-shutting-down-what-to-do/

You can also read the [official JFrog blog](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/) on this.

Comment: Could you pls assist me to do the necessary modifications in gradle files as per the reference you shared?

Comment: I don't know where this package artifacts were moved to. Go to https://github.com/lukaville and open an issue asking about this. Maybe they need to rebuild and release this to maven central.

Comment: from jfrog's blog post: UPDATE 4/27/2021: We listened to the community and will keep JCenter as a read-only repository indefinitely. Our customers and the community can continue to rely on JCenter as a reliable mirror for Java packages.

Answer (score 0):

Although Bintray is not accepting any new libraries, the existing libraries are still available as read-only so there should not be a problem there.

Comment: you got that idea or it refers to any doc or reference?

Comment: check their last update on this page: https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/

Comment: please mention all references in your answer.

Comment: [What happens after the sunset of Bintray?](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/)

On May 1, 2021, the sunset will impact all existing Bintray users. Bintray users will be blocked and will no longer be able to use the Bintray service. This includes existing software distribution, account administrative access, UI access, and the REST API.