# Android : Could not GET/Find get repos from bintray.com

Tags: java, android, maven

Trying to run old project with following config in `build.gradle` (root) file.

**build.gradle (root)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
//        jcenter() //deprecated
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.6.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
//        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3' //getting error because of this error so commented

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
//        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" } //getting error because of this error so commented 
        maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
        mavenCentral()
        //        jcenter() //deprecated

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
  
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 17
        buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 68
        //versionName "9.1.2"
        versionName "9.1.4"
        multiDexEnabled true
//        renderscriptTargetApi 17
//        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        //signingConfig signingConfigs.config

    }


    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false

        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        jumboMode = true
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
        exclude '.readme'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/README.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'

    // http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/customtabs

    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation files('libs/eSewaSdk.aar')

    //debugging
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.6.0'

    //universal dimension for all devices
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'

    // compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'

    //AutoValue
    compileOnly 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5'
    annotationProcessor "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5"
    compileOnly 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-gson:0.4.5'
    implementation 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-parcel-adapter:0.2.5'
    annotationProcessor 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-gson:0.4.5'
    annotationProcessor 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-parcel:0.2.5'

    //GSON
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    implementation('com.fatboyindustrial.gson-jodatime-serialisers:gson-jodatime-serialisers:1.5.0') {
        exclude group: "joda-time", module: "joda-time"
    }
    implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.5.1'

    //Network
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'

    // http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp
    implementation group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '3.6.0'


    // http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/logging-interceptor
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp-urlconnection

    //    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.12.0'

    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'

    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.0'

    //rx java
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.7'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay2:rxrelay:2.0.0'

    // http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.pwittchen/reactivenetwork-rx2
    implementation 'com.github.pwittchen:reactivenetwork-rx2:2.1.0'

    //dagger setup
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'

    //Butterknife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'

    /*firebase*/
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:17.0.0'


    //implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
//    implementation 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.4.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.travijuu:numberpicker:1.0.7'

    /*sqlite debugging*/

//    debugImplementation 'im.dino:dbinspector:3.4.1@aar'

    /*for mulriddex enabled*/
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.ramotion.paperonboarding:paper-onboarding:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.sqlbrite2:sqlbrite:2.0.0'

    /*scanner*/
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'

    /*google play services*/
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:16.2.0'

    // http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-auth
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0'
    //Dependencies for the REST API example
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev139-1.22.0'

    /*search view*/
    implementation 'com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.0'
//    implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:8.0.1'

    /*glide*/
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.github.firdausmaulan:GlideSlider:1.3.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8'
    implementation 'org.michaelbel:bottomsheet:1.2.3'
    implementation 'com.mindorks.android:prdownloader:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.thijsk:TouchImageView:v1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'


    //timer
    implementation 'com.github.iwgang:countdownview:2.1.6'

    /*notification badger*/

    /*color ful toast*/
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.miguelbcr:RxPaparazzo:0.6.0-2.x'
    implementation 'com.github.javiersantos:AppUpdater:2.7'
    implementation 'com.github.scottyab:showhidepasswordedittext:0.8'

    //pinview
    implementation 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.4.2'

    /*Progressbar*/
    implementation 'com.budiyev.android:circular-progress-bar:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'

    // required for deeplink (branch.io)
    implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:3.+'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'


    implementation 'com.github.Jay-Goo:RangeSeekBar:v2.0.4'

    //map

    implementation 'com.patloew.rxlocation:rxlocation:1.0.5'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'


    implementation 'com.github.traex.expandablelayout:library:1.2.2'
    implementation 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.6.0@aar'

    implementation 'com.hanks:htextview-typer:0.1.6'


//    implementation 'com.willowtreeapps.spruce:spruce-android:1.0.1'

    /*must be removed on relese*/

    implementation 'com.instabug.library:instabug:8.0.13'

    /*firebase*/
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:17.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:10.0.1'
    //gif image
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.17'

    implementation 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.6.0@aar'


    //badge
    implementation "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.22@aar"

    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.19'

    implementation 'com.github.ApendIr:slider:1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

}
```

**Got Error:**

1:
`Could not GET 'http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml'`

`Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway`

2:`Could not resolve com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3`

I got it, Since `jcenter()` is shutdown, i need to use `mavenCentral()` and find replacement for outdated packages. i tried to replace with `mavenCentral()`. and try to find alternative but could not.. tried with commenting, those error giving repos, but still can not fetch my required dependencies.

Referred to
[Android Studio: Gradle sync failed: Could not HEAD '...'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67804266/could-not-get-https-dl-bintray-com-lukaville-maven-com-nbsp-library-1-09)

[Difference among mavenCentral(), jCenter() and mavenLocal()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726435/difference-among-mavencentral-jcenter-and-mavenlocal)

[Bintray is now sunsetted](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/)

[Jcenter 502 bad gateway after gradle refresh](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/04/migration-from-bintray/)

Any suggestion on migration or package replacement or quick fix would be great help.. Thank you.

**Full stacktrace**

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project /Users/nabrajkhadka/OfficeProjects/Native-Android/android-master


> Configure project :app
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"DSL element 'android.dataBinding.enabled' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'android.buildFeatures.dataBinding'.\nIt will be removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (30.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 4.2.2.\nAndroid SDK Build Tools 30.0.2 will be used.\nTo suppress this warning, remove \"buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'\" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.","sources":[{}]}
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug FAILED
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeGenClassesDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
> Task :app:dataBindingTriggerDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets FAILED
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build completed with 8 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

4: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

5: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

6: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

7: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

8: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 26s
21 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 13 up-to-date
```

Comment: http://dl.bintray.com is dead... apart from not using https instead of http...

Comment: https://www.infoq.com/news/2021/02/jfrog-jcenter-bintray-closure/

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes.. just trying to get workaround or quick fixes :)

Answer (score 6):

if you go to the missing library's [Github](https://github.com/michaelbel/BottomSheet) page, you see that it was available only through `jcenter`, and since `jcenter` is **down**, you need to clone the library and build it yourself and put it on the classpath.

Comment: Hy @mohsen. Thanks for the answer,  Actually a good answer but tried with repo cloning and manually integrating it but still other errors are persisting. There should be a official guide for migration, isn't it?

Comment: The repo said to use material bottomSheet, but I do not know anything about migration. you should probably check the material bottomSheet to see how it is used.