# How can fix this issue for ant deployment

Tags: build, ant, salesforce, bintray

error we are getting the SERVER ERROR: Bad Gateway url=https://dl.bintray.com/valmaev/maven/com/aquivalabs/force/ant/antforce/0.10/antforce-0.10.pom
[ivy:retrieve]  SERVER ERROR: Bad Gateway url=https://dl.bintray.com/valmaev/maven/com/aquivalabs/force/ant/antforce/0.10/antforce-0.10.jar during deployment of code to salesforce org

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X95ti.png

> ivysetting.xml we using for code deployment

```
<ivysettings>
<settings defaultResolver="bintray" />
<resolvers>
    <chain name="bintray">
        <bintray />
        <bintray subject="valmaev" repo="maven" />
    </chain>
</resolvers>
```

Comment: dl.bintray.com is not responding to pings.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67804266/could-not-get-https-dl-bintray-com-lukaville-maven-com-nbsp-library-1-09