# What is the fix for could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1. in flutter vscode?

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':audioplayers'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':audioplayers:classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1.
> Required by:
> project :audioplayers
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom'.
> > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> > Remote host terminated the handshake
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':audioplayers' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':path_provider'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Answer (score 1):

Need to enable other protocol versions for fetching from Maven repo, add the following

> allowInsecureProtocol = true

in your project build.gradle file

```
  repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral(){
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error when happening the android studio can not update the Gradle file from their servers see this link to solve [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63157065/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle4-0-1-or-any-version)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify protocols other than TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2 in gradle.properties. 
e.g.

> TLSv1.0 SSLv1.0 ...

Example:

```
systemProp.https.protocols=TLSv1.0,SSLv1.0,SSLv2.0,SSLv3.0
```