# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, build.gradle, firebase-storage

I'm using Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 Patch 2, Gradle 7.5.1, Android Gradle Plugin Version 7.3.1, Build Tools 33.0.0, SDK 32. The current stable Gradle [release](https://gradle.org/install/) is 7.5.1.

It appears that the recent Firebase `bom` update from `30.5.0` to `31.0.0` has issues. Does anyone know a fix?

About a week ago I started working on a Kotlin project and added Firebase Auth to it, everything worked fine:

```
dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.5.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
}
```

Today I had to include the Storage and RealTimeDatabase. I go to the [Storage SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start), it says to add:

```
dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
}
```

When I `sync`, I get warnings:

> Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.0
>
> Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics
>
> Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx
>
> Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx
>
> Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx

[image]

Once I `build`, it **fails**, inside the project I get:

> Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

[image]

The odd thing is once I revert back to `bom:30.5.0` and only use `firebase-analyticss` && `firebase-auth-ktx` **everything works fine**.

**UPDATE**
I got the most recent version numbers [from here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries) and tried to sync the below but the same issued occurred:

```
dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.1.0'
}
```

I've filed this same bug to the [firebase-android-sdk gitbub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was cause by:

> Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

To dig deeper into the issue, I went **inside Android Studio (not your mac)**, at the bottom I opened **Terminal** and entered: `./gradlew build --warning-mode all`

The exact problem was:

> PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target

To fix the issue I found the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63235324/4833705) by @Sadegh

I went to `Gradle Scripts` > `gradle.properties`. Inside the `gradle.properties` file paste the below 6 lines from his answer:

```
// ...

systemProp.http.proxyHost=fodev.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8118
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.jitpack.io, *.maven.org
systemProp.https.proxyHost=fodev.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8118
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.jitpack.io, *.maven.org
```